# How do I embed a power Bi report without access token?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I don't need single sign on. It's OK to let user login power bi when access embeded report. I just need the bookmark pane show up.

My application does not need authentication, and my company's AD is not on Azure so I can't register my app on Azure AD even if I want to.

I'm OK with user need to login Power BI when they access embedded reports. But I do need to make the bookmark pane visible, as far as I research that needs some javascript code that only accepts embed URL from Power BI Rest API and access token.

But shouldn't my situation that don't need single sign on only need to show a pane much easier? Is it possible?

Comment: If you want users to log into Power BI using their own identities, then follow the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization?tabs=net-core

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for the reponse, but the first step in the instruction is register an Azure AD app, which is what we don't have.

Comment: Power BI only supports Azure AD.  Period.  So if your users log in to Power BI, you have Azure AD.